# Re-scan LUN on Linux

Tags: linux, storage, scsi

We have expend existing LUN size on EMC Storage and now i want to re-scan on Host side but i don't know how to figure out SCSI ID of that specific LUN. I am new to storage.. This is what i am doing but don't know whether it is a right way or not

```
Pseudo name=emcpowerj
CLARiiON ID=APM00112500570 [Oracle_Cluster]
Logical device ID=200601602E002900B6BCA114C9F8E011 [LUN01]
state=alive; policy=CLAROpt; priority=0; queued-IOs=0;
Owner: default=SP A, current=SP A       Array failover mode: 1
==============================================================================
--------------- Host ---------------   - Stor -   -- I/O Path --  -- Stats ---
###  HW Path               I/O Paths    Interf.   Mode    State   Q-IOs Errors
==============================================================================
   2 qla2xxx                  sdaj      SP A1     active  alive       0      1
   2 qla2xxx                  sdaw      SP B1     active  alive       0      4
   1 qla2xxx                  sdj       SP A0     active  alive       0      1
   1 qla2xxx                  sdw       SP B0     active  alive       0      4
```

Here i am running find command on sdX device to find out SCSI ID to i can do `echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/X:X:X:X/rescan` to do re-scan LUN

```
$ find /sys/devices -name "*block*" | grep -e "sdaj" -e "sdaw" -e "sdj" -e "sdw"
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:05:00.1/host2/rport-2:0-1/target2:0:1/**2:0:1:8**/block:sdaw
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:05:00.1/host2/rport-2:0-0/target2:0:0/**2:0:0:8**/block:sdaj
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:05:00.0/host1/rport-1:0-1/target1:0:1/**1:0:1:8**/block:sdw
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:05:00.0/host1/rport-1:0-0/target1:0:0/**1:0:0:8**/block:sdj
```

or there is a alternative or other way to scan LUN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the "lsscsi" program, which is probably available for your distribution.

```
% lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR00 1.00  /dev/sr0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    VMware,  VMware Virtual S 1.0   /dev/sda
[2:0:1:0]    disk    VMware,  VMware Virtual S 1.0   /dev/sdb
```

As for rescanning the bus, that's pretty much it.